# Finding if two points on elliptic curve are related

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

On a given elliptic curve I have some points that are defined like this:
Where
$$A=a*G$$
$$B=b*G$$
$$C=(a+b)*G$$
$$D=d*G$$
$$E=(a+d)*G$$
So finally I have two equations like below:
$$A+B=C$$
$$A+D=E$$

Given the values $(C,E,A)$, is there any way I can prove that point $A$ is common in both the points $C$ and $E$?

Or can I also prove that point $A$ is part of the $C$ and $E$?

Comment: Hint: Could you do it with normal numbers?

Comment: @SEJPM, okay got it, I'm trying but I couldn't able to figure it out, I don't think this is any unsolvable problem, I feel there exists some solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you can't.**

I'll make the argument over the integers, it directly transfers to ECC points.

Suppose you have two integers $c,e\in\mathbb Z$. You can now prove *for every* $a\in\mathbb Z$ that $c$ and $e$ have $a$ "in common".

For this you simply pick $b=c-a$ and $d=e-a$ and now you have the "proof" that both have $a$ in common. Note how *no restrictions whatsoever* have been placed on $a,c,e$ so it works with all triples.

Comment: I may wrongly presented the question, now I made some edits and made the question much clear.

Comment: @SaratG yes it is more clear, but my answer still stays valid :p

Comment: thank you for inputs, but here the situation is I have control over only C, E and A. I have restrictions over in picking up the values B and D.

Comment: @SaratG ahh, you didn't specify that. So are $d,b$ fixed by any means? Because if they are not and shall be recovered "on-the-fly", then my answer "literally" talks about the same $a,b,c,d,e$ as your question does.

Comment: d and b values are generated by some other networking entity which I didn't have control over. the values actually I receives are c and e. By somehow I know a, so here my job is to prove that whether a is part of c and e or not? Sorry to not to mention these details in the question.

Comment: @SaratG OK, so while they are fixed only <some-other-party> has knowledge of them, so only they can verify your guess for $a$. As stated in the answer, in theory you could come up with $d,b$ to convince yourself that $a$ is right, _for every choice of $a$_.

Comment: yes the <some-other-party> which I mentioned who has knowledge of d,b can verify that. I'm just looking at the possibility if I can verify it without having any knowledge of b,d then I can prove that the protocol which I'm studying is weak.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64064/discussion-between-sarat-g-and-sejpm).

Answer (score 1):

**Sometimes you can**

Actually, SEJPM has it mostly right; given a triplet $(cG, eG, aG)$, there will always be a possible $B, D$ such that $aG + B = cG$ and $aG + D = eG$.

However, they does leave open the question, given a triplet $(C, E, A)$, is it representable as $(cG, eG, aG)$?  If not, the first 5 equations cannot hold, and so we can know that the $C, E, A$ values we were given were not formed as specified.

A simple analogy in $\mathbb{Z}$ (the integers) would be if $G=2$, and we were given the triple $(4, 2, 7)$.  Even though there are values $B, D$ that are consistent with that triplet, we can also see that there are no sets of values $a, b, d$ that make $A$ odd (as $aG$ is always even; remember, $a$ cannot be a fraction), and so we can reject that.

So, the obvious question is: can that sort of thing happen with elliptic curves?  Well, the answer to that is "perhaps" (depending on the elliptic curve and whether you know the value $G$).

- There are elliptic curves that don't allow you to reject any triplet (as long as you know that $G$ is not the 'identity element')
- There are elliptic curves that, if you know what $G$ is, may allow you to reject some triplets (depending on what the value $G$ is).
- There are elliptic curves, that, even if you don't know what $G$ is, will allow you to reject some.

However, unless the elliptic curve was especially crafted, a random triplet has a good possibility of being accepted by any of the above tests.

Comment: Shouldn't the isomorphism between $(E(\mathbb F_p),+,G)$ and $(\mathbb Z_p,+,0)$ (where we map each point to its discrete log with respect to G) prevent that we can exclude any points / integers?

Comment: @SEJPM: there need not be any such isomorphism (at least, which extends over the entire group; of course, there will be an isomorphism if we consider only the subgroup generated by $G$); not all elliptic curve groups are cyclic.

Comment: @poncho, the curve here is closed and cyclic.

Comment: @SaratG: if the curve is cyclic (that is, there exists a point $G$ such that all points can be represented as $xG$, for some $x$), and has prime order, then it's the first case I gave ("you can't reject anything"); if it's cyclic but has a composite order (typically stated as cofactor > 1), then it's the second case I gave ("you might reject some things, depending on what $G$ is")